# Plot marginal probability distribution using python

Tags: python-3.x, probability, transfer-learning

How to plot (using python) marginal probability distribution of a given dataset such as one talked in transfer learning called P( X )?

Answer (score 0):

A marginal probability is just the sum of the joint of the specific variable you are concerned with. Seaborn library has a function for it.

[image: P(X)]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.jointplot(x=df["variableX"], y=df["variableY"], kind='scatter')
```